# Separating out facet_wrap using facet_wrap_paginate

Tags: ggplot2, facet-wrap, ggforce

I have never used facet_wrap_paginate before and am not finding any good examples of how to use it. Normally I use facet_wrap but save it as one plot and just increase the height and width.

Below I have put a simple example of the code I normally use to produce/save plots. Please note this is a very reduced version for the sake of simplicity.

```
   Draft <- 
   ggplot(aes(x, y) + 
   geom_boxplot() 

   ggsave(plot = Draft, "./Draft.jpeg", width = 15, height = 10, units = "cm")
```

However, I want to produce a multi-page PDF for the separated out by plot, using facet_wrap_paginate. When I ran the code (example below) I recieved no errors but was unable to find the output anywhere.

```
   Draft <- 
   ggplot(aes(x, y) + 
   geom_boxplot() +
   facet_wrap_paginate(~ chemical)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is, that `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate()` will produce separate plots of subsets of facets. You'd still have to place them in a pdf.

According to your description, you want plots of subsets of your dataset on separate pages of a PDF document.

Here is an example of how to do that without `facet_wrap_paginate()` in a quarto document. The idea is to split the dataset into subsets, then plot them with a `fig.height` so that each plot takes up one page.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
editor: visual
execute:
  echo: false
  message: false
  warning: false
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}
mtcars_cyl_split <- 
  mtcars |> 
  group_by(cyl) |> 
  group_split()
```

```{r}
#| fig-height: 6
walk(mtcars_cyl_split,
    \(x) print(ggplot(x, aes(mpg, disp, group = cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot()))
```
````